# Apache ./configure can't find pcre-config script

Tags: apache, pcre, configure

I'm trying to install Apache on Red Hat.  It's a system I don't have full control over (my sysadmins have given me a directory to work in).  So I've downloaded, configured, and installed APR, APR-Util, and PCRE, in addition to Apache 2.4.7.

I ran the following for APR:

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apr/
make
make install
```

Received the warning to remember to run

```
libtool --finish /usr/local/apr/lib
```

I changed that to

```
libtool --finish /u01/app/apache/apr/lib/
```

and it said it installed the Libraries in that location

Similarly, for APR-Util, ran:

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin
make
make install
```

Told me the Libraries were installed in /u01/app/apache/apr-util//lib

Next, PCRE:

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/pcre/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin --with-apr-util=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/bin
make
make install
```

So far, no problems.  Now I try to configure apache

```
./configure --prefix=/u01/app/apache/apache247/ --with-apr=/u01/app/apache/apr/bin --with-apr-util=/u01/app/apache/apr-util/bin --with-pcre=/u01/app/apache/pcre/bin
```

It finds APR and APR-Util, but of course, I get the error "Did not find pcre-config script at /u01/app/apache/pcre/bin".  Why, I don't know, as the file is there at that location.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question

Comment: This used to be the place to go for help, "pure" programming or not.

Comment: @Shawn this belongs on Super User

Comment: It is not that you won't get answers, I just think Super User will be the right place

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob with apache.  Never used Super User before.  I'll try that, and hope for answers in both places.  Thanks.

Comment: SuperUser folks are sending me back here to understand where to place the #! to run ./configure.  Apache docs don't mention needing an interpreter to run the configure.  Any thoughts?